# Fractional Derivatives

Tags: nt.number-theory, pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, quantization, chaos

How far these Theories of "Fractional Derivatives" be rigorized ? I have few books and references on Fractional Differential Equations etc (mainly they stress on Applied Mathematics parts and similar problems of Physics), but I need a rigorous account of "Fractional Derivatives" acting as Operators in "Concrete Spaces" in a very specific sense (should be clear from the context, I have no idea !), it seems there is some link between "Ito Calculas" of Stochastic Integration  and Fractional Derivatives and with Theory of Distributions  (may be in some loose sense) Specifically the link between The Theory of Distributions and "Fractional Derivatives", for say we know Dirac Delta function is "Distributional Derivative" of Heaviside unit function, however, in a similar fashion can we extend this fractional derivatives ? If yes, then in what space ? on which kind of functions it acts, what is the topology this spaces do enjoy etc. .Also it seems there is "some" relationship between "Fractals" and Fractional derivatives. can anyone help me regarding this ?

Comment: There is a book titled "The fractional calculus" by Oldham and Spanier, one of whom is a mathematician. I recall it contains quite general developments of the various notions of fractional derivative.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Smith, this book is in our Library, looking through it, now

Comment: You have quite a few questions here.  If you can focus your question on one specific topic, making it read less like a "tell me about fractional derivatives" request, you could likely get your question re-opened.  As is, your question is too multi-faceted and it's unclear what would get to the core of what you need.

Comment: At least I need to know the "rule" of differentiation and on which kind of functions it acts.

Comment: Actually I got what I wanted to know, Prof Lapidus (math.ucr.edu/~lapidus/) provided me the reference, it's in Schwartz's Theorie des distributions ,Chapter VI, Section 5 (convolution product)  (Hermann, Paris, 1978), hopefully now my question might get some meaning. Thank you everyone for helping.